Can I partially recaulk a walk-in shower
Recently moved into a place and noticed there’s quite a bit of mold in the walk-in shower. It’s a walk-in shower tiled from ceiling to floor. From what I can tell the mold only exists at the bottom part of the shower (along the horizontal caulking close to the floor and lower part along the vertical caulking on the walls).
I removed the caulk around the floor and the lower part along the wall because that’s the only area where there’s mold. I am hoping that I can just recaulk the areas that I removed, can I do that? Or do I need to remove all caulking in the shower and then reapply (which I really dont want to do because that would mean I need to remove a lot more caulk including the caulk from the ceiling).
Any advice is appreciated!

You need to inspect all the caulking and replace any that's failed, not just the parts where mold is currently growing.

When resealing any space, remember what you're trying to achieve - avoiding water escaping. Do you need to redo the entire space? Strictly speaking no, but there is always a risk that joins between old and new product don't seal perfectly. My advice would be to pay attention to where the water goes - around the floors and lower walls - loads. Around the ceiling, not so much. Therefore I'd go as high on the vertical as you can. That way, if joins aren't perfect, the risk of that actually causing you a problem is minimised.
However I must also draw attention to FreeMans comment, make sure you properly inspect all the caulking and replace any that's failed.
